# Running protractor scripts using Docker Image

Tags: docker, protractor, dockerfile

I am trying to run my protractor scripts using docker image(Dockerfile) .
For same I am using base image as alpine , and copying my working code in that  using COPY command.
My docker image looks like below but I am not sure how to install chrome browser into it due to which it is failing while running the test execution command.

```
FROM node
RUN mkdir src
COPY ./_pages /src/_pages
COPY ./_tests /src/_tests
COPY ./config /src/config
COPY ./reports /src/reports
COPY ./resources /src/resources
COPY ./src /src/src
COPY ./test_suites /src/test_suites
COPY package.json /src/package.json
COPY tsconfig.json /src/tsconfig.json
COPY tslint.json /src/tslint.json
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN  sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable
WORKDIR /src
RUN npm install
RUN npm run webdriver-update
RUN npm run webdriver-update-local
RUN npm run build
RUN apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
ENTRYPOINT npm test
```

When I build+run this image and ran npm test command to execute the scripts. It gives me below error(because of no chrome driver present):

```
[15:32:59] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:32:59] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[15:33:01] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://172.17.0.11:47860/wd/hub
[15:33:21] E/launcher - Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'c9699349ca76', ip: '172.17.0.11', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.184-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_232'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[15:33:21] E/launcher - WebDriverError: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'c9699349ca76', ip: '172.17.0.11', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.184-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_232'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Can anyone suggest me how to add command to install chrome as a part of docker image?

Comment: According to this you should be able to just install the `chromium` package. https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/chromium

What do the `webdriver-update` and `webdriver-update-local` scripts look like?

Comment: Can you share your capabilites section of your protractor configuration file. I am confused about the root of the error. Bit more information would be great!!

Comment: Pls find the capability section: capabilities: {
        browserName: configuration.dafault_browser,
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: parseInt(EnvironmentParams.getEnvironmentParams().threadsCount),
        chromeOptions: {
            w3c: false,
            args: [ '--headless', 'no-sandbox' ]
        }
    },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be two reasons for this error:

1) You might not have set the `"--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--no-sandbox"` flags in your chrome capabilities because of which your server is not starting docker does not support this.

2) Try to connect to chrome directly without using a selenium server by setting the `directConnect: true`

3) For installing dependencies related to chrome, you can use the following command:

```
ENV CHROME_PACKAGE="google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb"

RUN echo "deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget sudo && \
    apt-get -f install -y -t stretch openjdk-8-jre-headless ca-certificates-java && \
    wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg --unpack ${CHROME_PACKAGE} && \
    apt-get install -f -y && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    rm ${CHROME_PACKAGE}
```

Make sure to run your docker image with a privilaged flag and mouth the dev/shm to .a volume.

Comment: Thanks Sankalan Parajuli , Will implement this approach and will get back to you

Comment: Sankalan-  I have updated the question with recent docker file where I have added the command to install chrome dependencies(version-79.0.3945.88).

Comment: Try setting directConnect: true in your protractor config file and try again.

Comment: Okay but with this configuration, our scripts are now getting executed on docker but we observed that whenever we try to run it on multiple instance(2 or more), it just hangs or  dont give any console output. Seems to be an issue with resources when using more than 1 chrome instance. Any idea how can we solve this issue.

Comment: If the above answer solved your problem, please accept the answer. You can solve the resources issue by mounting the dev/shm volume when you run your docker image. This will allow you to use the internal memory of the docker instance for computing. If you don't want to use the internal memory, you can mount a different volume. Here is an example `docker run -it --privileged --rm --net=host -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -v $(pwd)/report:/protractor/report protractor`. You can ask a different question for a detailed response.

Comment: Can you explain how can we increase the resource to run more than one browser in single container.
Currently we are running docker using:(we are using volume mapping "-v C:\QArepor\results:/src/reports" to get the reports in local machine)
docker run -it -v C:\QArepor\results:/src/reports <Docker Image>

Comment: The best would be to run all your tests in a selenium grid that is already running. You can use a docker compose script to turn them on and then use the selenium grid server URL as seleniumAddress. That way you will have specific browsers running as nodes. Other way would be to have your docker run in a kubernetes deployment where you can write a YAML file to define how much resources your container is going to request. Mounting the dev/shm is the last thing to do. This will not be scalable.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a base image with all necessary dependencies, e.g. [protractor-headless](https://hub.docker.com/r/webnicer/protractor-headless/)?

Comment: Thanks but we are looking forward to add all required dependencies from our end.

Comment: @user1931543 Fair enough